# Do method calls of javascript and python have the same structure?

Tags: javascript, python, function, this

I am a novice programmer. I noticed a similarity between python method calls and JavaScript f.call() function. I am curious if my observation is correct.

Let me present you what I know.

### Python Part

In python we declare methods as such:

```py
class Frog:
   def jump(self, distance):
     print("I am jumping the distance %d" % distance)
```

To run method one can do:

```py
green = Frog()
green.jump(5)    # "I am jumping the distance 5"
```

But the same result can be achieved with:

```py
Frog.jump(green, 5) # "I am jumping the distance 5"
```

This, to me, means that every method must be defined with the object of interest placed in the first parameter.

### JavaScript Part

Today I was surfing MDN and read [this article about *this* keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context) and [this article about *.call()* method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call#Syntax).

This is what I saw:

```
function add(c, d) {
  return this.a + this.b + c + d;
}

var o = {a: 1, b: 3};

// The first parameter is the object to use as
// 'this', subsequent parameters are passed as 
// arguments in the function call
add.call(o, 5, 7); // 16
```

Do you see how .call(object_of_interest, arg1, arg2, ...) structure in JavaScript is similar to jump(self, arg1, arg2, ...)? That flashed a light in my mind but I didn't feel very confident about my observation. Was that right? What was the relationship?

### Question (Edited on Sanyash)

I feel like seeing a cloudy relationship between classes, static or non static methods, how javascript interprets these and how python interprets these. But I couldn't make everything sit on a solid foot. So,

What is the connection I need to understand between these two languages or deduction I have to do on object oriented programming?  Anything taught new to me is really appreciated.

Comment: Your question body is well-written and formatted and shows research, but the question itself _What is the connection I need to understand between these two languages?_ is not really clear.

Comment: You need to learn how OOP works in Python and how it works in Javascript separately. After it you will see that they have something in common and something different.